# Artificial Intelligence Project - What language should I go for?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am a computer science student and I am going to work on an artificial intelligence project which will compose a musical tune according to the genre and mood inputs. Are the algorithms to be used for this project likely to be very resource-consuming? Would it make any difference (in terms of speed) if I choose to go with Java rather than C++? (Note : I know only these two languages and I am more comfortable with Java than C++.)

NB : Sorry for my poor English. If someone can, please clean up this post wherever necessary. Thanks.

Comment: This question comes up a lot. Short answer: choice of language is hardly ever a factor in performance of an application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The resource consumption is way more influenced by the algorithmic approach than the language chosen. If you are comfortable with Java, program your application in that language - even though a C++ implementation might be 10% faster.

That being said, you might be interested with [Artificial Intelligence API's for Java](https://aij.dev.java.net/).

Comment: A C++ implementation could easily be 10 times faster. I just ran into a case of Java taking 40 seconds to initialize an array of 16M vectors.

Comment: There are counter examples of awful memory leaks in C++. I think the point is to avoid premature optimization by using the language that the developer feels comfortable with.

Answer (score 13):

Go with Java since you are more comfortable with it.  That will allow you to concentrate on solving the problem, not the programming.  Maybe C++ would end with a faster program, maybe not, but getting there will be slower and you don't categorically state that the program must be blazingly fast.

Answer (score 3):

In my mind, the language mostly associated with AI is Lisp.

See the answers to [`Why is Lisp used for AI?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130475/why-is-lisp-used-for-ai) - top voted mentions this was the case in the 60s and 70s, but these days dynamic languages are used (ruby, python and such).

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you're at the proof-of-concept stage of your project.  I'd use whatever language your most comfortable with.  Well written Java code will run a lot faster then poorly written C.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Common Lisp for a project like this. If you don't know Lisp, I would learn it for this type of project. It would be a great learning experience and since you are a CS student, it will only help you. Lisp is a language that can be a real eye opener.

Comment: And many lisps (SBCL  for one) compile to native code.  Clojure is a lisp dialect which runs on the JVM, and integrates well with Java libraries, so he could get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar AI project a couple of years ago. I don't know what solution you will be implementing, but AI programs can generally be both resource consuming and may take a long time to run, but on the other hand, you'll need a language you're familiar with to get it done in time.

Therefore, my advice is that if you feel you *know* C++ (or C), go with one of them. If you don't know them, then consider carefully the time you will need to invest in learning a new language before choosing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting from scratch, use whatever you know best. If you want to use established libraries to speed up development, you might want to investigate that first - but Java is certain to have some.

In your shoes, I'd pick Java for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Clojure for the following reasons:

- It's a Lisp, and Lisps are great languages for AI development (partly historical, but also for some real concrete reasons - see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130475/why-is-lisp-used-for-ai) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224524/lisp-and-prolog-for-artificial-intelligence))
- Clojure runs on the JVM and has great Java interop, so you can exploit all the great Java AI libraries (e.g. [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)) plus you already have some experience of the Java environment
- JVMs have excellent optimizing JIT compilers nowadays, for all practical purposes you will get performance as fast as C/C++ for this kind of application.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is design everything you need first, every ADT, every algorithm class, hierarchy, everything. This kind of project/programming could be really hard to design in C/C++ family of languages, maybe you could choose other language with less string typed philosophy. So i encourage you with using a language designed for this kind of problem, better suited to your application, `functional paradigm` ex: LISP, `logical paradigm` ex: [PROLOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

My 3rd year dissertation project was an implementation of heuristics for cellular network radio frequency allocation. I chose Java over C++ because it allowed me to visualize the results much easier than if I'd used C++. I don't believe the performance would have been significantly different in C++ - the complexity factor of your algos is going to be the biggest factor probably.